# floating point number into two 16 bit integer in C

Tags: c

I wanted to convert a floating point number into two 16 bit integers. 
The code I've written is given below:

```
float floatCurrentVolume = 1234.50;

uint32_t ui32TemperaryVariable1;

uint16_t ui8ModbusRegister[2] = {0};

ui32TemperaryVariable2 =(uint32_t ) floatCurrentVolume;

ui8ModbusRegister[0]  = (uint16_t )(floatCurrentVolume &&  0x0000FFFF);

ui8ModbusRegister[1]  = (uint16_t )((ui32TemperaryVariable3 >> 16) && 0x0000FFFF);
```

Basically the floatCurrentVolume should be split into two 16 bit register. 
But when I check the output I get ui8ModbusRegister[0] = 0, ui8ModbusRegister[1] = 1.
What is wrong with the code??

Comment: __C__ `!=` __C++__ `!=` __C__, They are different languages and demand to be treated as such. :) Choose one and stick to that please.

Comment: Please indent your code properly using `Ctrl + K` or by indenting with four spaces. Also, C and C++ are two different languages, please choose one. This looks lke it is C though

Comment: `#ifdef __cplusplus` `#error C++ compiler` `#endif`

Answer (score 3):

You have wrong use case of `&&` and `&` characters. First case is *logical AND*  and result would be either `1` or `0` while second one is *bitwise AND* and this is what you are looking for.

```
ui8ModbusRegister[0]  = (uint16_t )(floatCurrentVolume &&  0x0000FFFF);
ui8ModbusRegister[1]  = (uint16_t )((ui32TemperaryVariable3 >> 16) && 0x0000FFFF);
```

should be

```
//                                                     |--here
ui8ModbusRegister[0]  = (uint16_t )(floatCurrentVolume &  0x0000FFFF);
ui8ModbusRegister[1]  = (uint16_t )((ui32TemperaryVariable3 >> 16) & 0x0000FFFF);
//                                                                 |--here
```

---

If you want to really send entire float number (including decimals) then you have to copy memory like below:

```
//Copy float to modbus register
memcpy(ui8ModbusRegister, &floatCurrentVolume, sizeof floatCUrrentVolume);

//And then on receive side, copy it back before read
memcpy(&floatCurrentVolume, ui8ModbusRegister, sizeof floatCUrrentVolume);
```

Comment: This is probably not the only problem. If he want's to have float value on 2 modbus registers `ui32TemperaryVariable2 =(uint32_t ) floatCurrentVolume;` should be replaced with `memcpy` too.

Comment: @user694733 That's true but from his point of view, he wanted it in integer. In case of entire float, then I agree with you, `memcpy` is required.

Comment: I suspect that he only said he wanted conversion to integer, because modbus protocol doesn't support floats out of the box. They are typically implemented using bitwise copy to 2 16-bit registers.

Answer (score 1):

The most portable way is to copy the float into the uint_t at the byte level. Any other way ends in involving undefined behaviour at a time or worse could use a float to int truncation. For example `ui32TemperaryVariable2 =(uint32_t ) floatCurrentVolume;` sets `ui32TemperaryVariable2` to `1234` which should not be what you expect.

The correct way is:

```
memcpy(ui8ModbusRegister, &floatCurrentVolume, sizeof(ui8ModbusRegister));
```

This correctly stores the high order 16 bits word in `ui8ModbusRegister[0]` and the low order one in `ui8ModbusRegister[1]`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe straight deep copy would be better?

```
float floatCurrentVolume = 1234.50;
uint16_t ui8ModbusRegister[2];
memcpy(ui8ModbusRegister, &floatCurrentVolume, 4);
```